# How do you activate JavaScript number rotator on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this JQuery script https://codepen.io/shivasurya/pen/FatiB to create a number rotator animation, but I need it to activate only when a user scrolls to that part of the page.

```
$('.count').each(function () {
$(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
}, {
    duration: 4000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function (now) {
        $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
    }
});
```

I'm new to JavaScript and JQuery, so is there any way to modify the script part of the code to make it load on scroll, not on document load?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by scrolling on that part of the page ?

You can use the scroll jquery function  https://api.jquery.com/scroll/

But keep in minds that the scroll function will be triggered on a element only if this element has its scrollbar displayed.

Comment: As in the element is further down the page, so the user has the scroll through the page to get to it. You can see the page here: dnsmadeeasy.com under the Our Network section.